# How to install dotNET 7 RC2 in App Service

Tags: sdk, azure-web-app-service, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a web site built using .NET 7 RC2, but when trying to deploy it to Azure AppServices, it fails with HTTP error 500.31.  When running *dotnet --info* on my AppService, I get the following list of SDK(s) which do not include RC2.

I need a feature that available on ASP.NET 7.  Is there a way to install the version I need?

[image]

Comment: I have created `.NET Core 7 App` and deployed to Azure App Service. Even I got the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmWET.png).

Comment: In `Azure Portal` => `App Service` => Configuration => `General Settings`, `.NET Version` is shown as [.NET 6(LTS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN4Zg.png).
 This is because .NET 7 is still in preview version. Even after updating the Version to .NET 7 (Preview), In KUDU Console I can see the version as [.NET 7 RC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwGJ.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created `.NET Core 7 App` and deployed to Azure App Service. Even I got the same error.

[image]

In `Azure Portal` => `App Service` => Configuration => `General Settings`, `.NET Version` is shown as .NET 6(LTS)

[image]

This is because .NET 7 is still in preview version. So by default, it is taken as .NET 6.

Even after updating the Version to .NET 7 (Preview), In KUDU Console I can see the version as `.NET 7 RC1`.
[image]

> How to install dotNET 7 RC2 in App Service

In Azure App service, we have 2 ways to install versions.

***Way1 :***

In `KUDU Console` => `Site extensions` => `Gallery` 
type `.NET Core 7`  in search box , you will find an option to install extensions.

Click on the `+` sign to install the required extension.

[image]

Path to SCM - `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/`

***Way2:***

Navigate to `Azure Portal` => Your `App Service` => Under `Developer Tools` Click on `Extensions` => `Add`

Search for `asp.net core` , you will find runtime versions related to `.NET 7 RC2`

[image]

Select the required `extension` and click on  `Accept legal terms` and click on `OK`

After adding the extensions in Azure App Service, In VS i have tried to Publish again, I got the below Warning

[image]

It clearly says that,In Azure App Service there is no support for `.NET 7 RC2` as of now.

Under `Settings` => Change the `Deployment  Mode` to `Self-contained`,Save  and Publish the App.
[image]

Now Iam able to access the App without any issues.

[image]

Comment: Harshitha,

That was exactly what I was missing.  Thanks for the detail you included.  It is very helpful.

Comment: Wow man, thanks. way2 worked for me. Why tf would Azure not include .Net Core 7 runtime if is selected that stack under the App Services configuration? it doesnt make sense.