# Azure App Service - .net versions support - updates (HTTP 500.31 Error)?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Today we pushed a .net 7 web app to Azure and suddenly everything crashed:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

We had to republish as **self contained** (+ had to change the publish settings from 32bit to 64bit (also in the App service general configuration)).

Now, with self contained, it seems to work.

No idea why it never happened before. Yesterday we published and everything was working. Today just a css update, and the resulting HTTP 500.31 error.

After searching I found a SO thread where an update in the Extensions (App Service > Development Tools) was causing the 500.31 error, but in our case it didn't solve it.

When we did `dotnet --info` via the Azure console of the app service we saw that Microsoft.NetCore.Appcore / Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.2 was installed and .net sdk 7.0.102.

However when viewing our `projectname.runtimeconfig.json` via App Service Editor it was set to `"version": "7.0.5"`

What does this mean regarding the installed .net (sdk) versions?

Does Microsoft update/deploy only specific versions of .net / .net sdk's to Azure App Services? (If so, is there a list of the updates/supported versions and when they update?)

Or do we manually need to install new .net / .net sdk for an App Service in Azure using the version specific dotnet-install scripts ?

Comment: Check Event logs on Server.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839745/troubleshooting-500-31-ancm-on-azure-app-service

Comment: no clue there, that post gave us the hint for selfcontained.

Comment: Can you please share your code repo?

Comment: HTTP error 501 is not implemented. So you connection completed and you passed authentication.  So most likely a header like Content-Type is wrong.

Comment: Once check the .NET Runtime in `Azure App Service`? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpviG.png).Make sure it is set to `.NET 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [HTTP 500.31 Error

This error generally occurs when there is compatibility issue with the version we are using and the deployed Azure App.

- I have deployed the `.NET Core 7` WebApp to `Azure App Service`.

[image]

> do we manually need to install new .net / .net sdk for an App Service in Azure using the version specific dotnet-install scripts ?

No, It is not required to install the new `.net` / `.net sdk` for an `App Service`.

As you have mentioned check the versions of the .NET available in KUDU Console using `dotnet --info`.

[image]

[image]

If you want to use any specific version which is not there is `Azure App Service`, then you can install it manually using the `dotnet-install` script.

- Just we need to check the version in `Configuration` => `General Settings`.

[image]

- Even my `WebApplication1.runtimeconfig.json` version in App Service editor is also `7.0.0`.

[image]

- To know more about the error in detail, update the `stdoutLogEnabled` to true in `web.config` and check the logs in `C:\home\LogFiles`.

As your Azure console of the app service is showing  `Microsoft.NetCore.Appcore / Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.2` and `.net sdk 7.0.102.` and the `projectname.runtimeconfig.json` is set to "version": "7.0.5"`,

- It clearly says that the version 7.0.5 is not available in the Azure App Service.
- If you don't want to deploy the app as self-contained, either change the version in `runtimeconfig.json` or install the new version from Extensions.

[image]

Refer similar type of issue in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74144925/how-to-install-dotnet-7-rc2-in-app-service/74163003?noredirect=1#comment134348099_74163003) which I have resolved.